# Is it possible to show progress/ update bar while writing files usinfg FileStream

Tags: c#, asp.net

i m working on a web application that reads files from some where and writes it down on the disk using `System.IO.FileStream` class. Is it possible to display some kind of progress bar or update bar while i write these files.

Here is sample code

```
using (Stream input = getResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (FileStream output = new FileStream(saveTo1, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    int bytesRead;

                    while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))>0)
                    {
                        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: What control have you used to upload file?

Comment: Nothing. Its just like a simple file copy from one location to another

Comment: hmmm ok then try "SHAKIR SHABBIR"'s answer it will work for you.

Comment: Hmmm.. I am working on that right now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Update Progress.

What you need to do?

- Place a button that writes the file stream when clicked into an
  Update Panel say "UPanelOperation".
- Place the following lines of code in the update panel before the closing Content           Template tag.
- Please change the image name to whatever image you have in the following lines of code

  ```
  <asp:UpdateProgress ID="updateProgress" runat="server" DisplayAfter="0" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UPanelOperation">
      <ProgressTemplate>
          <div id="progressBackgroundFilter">
          </div>
          <div align="center">
              <img src="../../css/images/1-0.gif" />&nbsp;Please Wait...</div>
      </ProgressTemplate>
  </asp:UpdateProgress>
  ```

Comment: That was really helpful. But this image will be static. Can't i display the proper updating imgae or a proper progress bar

Comment: Yes, you can try getting a gif image that display the progress bar in marquee style and you will get what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Edit your code as follows:

```
while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))>0)
                {
                    label1.Text = buffer.ToString() + " bytes transfered.";
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
```

...where label1 is a control you place on the form.

Comment: I have already tried this. First, Its just displaying the data at the end when file copy is complete. And Second, Even if it starts working after some digging, its actually not a progress bar but just a status.

Comment: To solve that, you will have to issue the below statement just before you set label1.Text=... to make your form interactive: System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()

Comment: If I understand correct, this code is called from your ASP.NET code and you want to show the status to the end-user sitting on his browser on the other side of the world? In that case, I think you will have to use AJAX and HttpXMLRequest object on client.